# Nginx: Rewrite to remove last path from $uri

Tags: nginx

I'm moving all document from `/docs/path/to/sub/*.pdf` to their parent folder, `/docs/path/to/*.pdf`.

How to redirect from old url:

`example.com/docs/path/to/sub/file.pdf`

to new url

`example.com/docs/path/to/file.pdf`

I'm using method below but not work:

```
location /docs/ {
  rewrite ^/docs/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)\.(.*)$  /docs/$1/$2/$3/$5 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `permanent` flag which means a redirect, the URL would probably return 404 after the redirect, try replacing `permanent` with `last` and see if it works.

**EDIT:**

I think your mistake is that you are matching the extension, so you are doing the counting wrong, you don't have enough capturing blocks. I'd like to do it in a more dynamic way though, not sure if this will work.

```
location ^~ /docs(.*)/([^/]+)/(.*) {
    try_files $uri @redirect;
}
location @redirect {
    return 301 $scheme$http_host/docs$1$3;
}
```

if not you can change your current rewrite, assuming you have 5 capturing blocks,

```
/docs/$1/$2/$4$5
```

last 2 are file+extension

Comment: Already do but no luck. Yes, I want to redirect. Added some info about redirect.

Comment: Thanks AbuShady. I also like in more dynamic way, but either two not work. Right now, I'm `proxy_pass` to Apache for location /docs/ and using `RedirectMatch permanent ^/docs/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+).pdf$ /docs/$1/$2/$4.$5` in `.htaccess`

Comment: you can easily debug this because you can see the output URL on the browser, what URL did my conf generate ?

Comment: Using your `@redirect` conf nothing change at URL (not redirect).